# Reputation earned in migrated answers

Tags: support

So, I recently answered a question in regular Board & Card Games. I got a lot of upvotes, and thus a lot of reputation.

Unfortunately, I woke up this morning to find that the question had been migrated to Meta. This has caused all the reputation I earned from my answer to disappear into the ether, since reputation which is "earned in Meta" does not count.

Since the reputation was actually earned in the regular forum, is there any way I can get the reputation back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the site working as intended. If a question belongs on meta, then main-site reputation should not be awarded for it or its answers, regardless of where it was originally posted.

That said, I'm a bit baffled by the specific situation. Presumably it's [this one](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1840/409) (you've only answered one question here on meta), and that question doesn't appear to be a question for meta. The other close reason originally used was that it was a game recommendation question, but that *also* doesn't apply. So I've undone the migration and reopened it. It's possible for it to still be off-topic, but it's not obviously off-topic to me, so I don't think it's appropriate for me to unilaterally close it.

So, if nothing changes, I believe you will get reputation back, but to be very clear, this is *not* because you answered while it was on the main site. Reputation should always be awarded based on where the question belongs, not where it was posted.

As a final note, there are only three upvotes on your answer there. You can get that much reputation *very* easily, so I wouldn't regard this as a substantial loss, no matter what ultimately happens.

Comment: Thanks. It was more about the principle than the actual reputation. I apreciate your help.

Comment: I see - well, in principle, we should expect not to keep reputation if we answer questions that are migrated or deleted. Think of it as incentive to consider whether the question actually belongs before answering :)

Comment: I totally agree, I just wanted to establish a precedent one way or the other.